# What is the probability that a given function has the property that for distinct elements from its domain x,y f(x)=f(y)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let F be the set of all functions mapping {1,..n} to {1,...m}.
Let f be a function that is chosen uniformly at random from F. Let x,y be distinct elements from the set {1,..n}. Let p denote the probability that f(x) = f(y). Then, p = ?

I couldn't actually understand the question.

Is this how it needs to be done?

p = # functions with property f(x)=f(y)/ Total number of functions?

If so, I know the answer. If else, can I please know the correct approach. ?

Comment: Need to find the probability for a given function $f$, that there exists at least one pair $x,y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. There's different cases to consider such as $m < n$, I would start with breaking into the cases where $m \leq n$ and $m > n$.

Comment: For m>n, it's 1 right ? Because the function is not injective ?

Comment: And, how to go about the case when m<=n ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're asking: Given $n, m, x, y$, what is $p$? In this case, the answer is as you suggest: $$p = \frac{\text{num functions with } f(x)=f(y)}{\text{total num functions}}.$$

The total number of possible functions is $m^n$ since we need to make $n$ choices and each choice has $m$ options.

The number of functions with $f(x) = f(y)$ is $m^{n-1}$ since we don't get to choose $f(y)$: it is automatically chosen once we fix $f(x)$. That means we only have $n-1$ choices to make this time.

Overall we get
$$p = \frac{m^{n-1}}{m^n} = \boxed{\frac 1 m}.$$

---

Commenter @oliverjones mentioned a different interpretation: Given $n, m$, what's the probability that there exists some $x, y$ with $x \not = y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$? In other words, what's the probability that $f$ is *not* injective? This version would be answered using different methods. I'll answer this too so you can see the difference, and just in case this might have been the question you intended in the first place.

If $n > m$ then the function can never be injective, so the probability is $1$.
Otherwise, we need to count the number of injective functions. There are $\binom{m}{n}$ ways to decide which $n$ values to use, and then $n!$ ways to assign those values to specific inputs, for a total of $\binom{m}{n} n! = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$ injective functions. There are still $m^n$ total functions, so we get the probability that our randomly chosen function is non-injective:
$$1 - \frac{\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}}{m^n} = \boxed{1 - \frac{m!}{m^n (m-n)!}}.$$

Comment: Can you brief the first part ? My reasoning is. x has m elements to be mapped , y has to mapped to f(x) , so m*1*m^n-2/m^n which turns out to be 1/m ?

Comment: I've edited more explanation into my answer to make it complete. But the explanation you gave in your comment is valid too. (It ends up basically saying the same thing as my version.)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing $f$ uniformly at random from all possible functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ is equivalent to choosing $f(x)$ uniformly at random from $\{1,\dots,m\}$ for each $x$. So, for example, the probability that $f(1)=1$ is $\frac1m$. For any given $x,y$, the probability that $f(x)=y$ is $\frac1m$.